# Installing jems-installer on headless server, error

Tags: linux, redhat, installation, java, jboss

I'm trying to install JBoss on one of our virtual servers. I downloaded the jems-installer to install JBoss, but it's expecting to run in a GUI. This is the error I get.

```
[root@S3WEB tmp]# java -jar jems-installer-1.2.1.CR4.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/java/jre1.6.0_25/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Color.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.InstallData.<init>(InstallData.java:51)
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.GUIInstaller.<init>(GUIInstaller.java:107)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:62)
```

How can I install JBoss without a GUI then.

System: Redhat Linux Enterprise 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JBoss documentation has [an entry for this question](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/installguide/r1/en/html_single/#automated_install). This link is for JBoss 4, but I guess the general approach has not changed, yet. Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, stupid me. I had skimmed through that page, should've read it more carefully. Apparently, I'm supposed to use the jems-installer jar to install jboss. I was attempting to install jems-installer, thinking its installation was a prequisite to jboss. Thanks for the link Axel!